# telnet to 10.0.2.15:2323 - The Emulator IP Address

Tags: android

I am trying the PJSIP on the Android and to emulate the commands on the Android, it asks us to telnet to 10.0.2.15:2323.

But when I try to telnet from my terminal it doesn't allow to telnet.

What I found was telnet localhost 5554, it works to access the emulator.

Please how can I telnet to 10.0.2.15:2323?

Comment: PJSIP is what exactly?

Comment: Look here[PJSUA-CLI Wiki](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSUA-CLI) and test the `--cli-telnet-port=2323`

Comment: How do I run the command --cli-telnet-port=2323

Comment: PJSIP is a soft phone....

Comment: Hello Alex, How to we run the pjsua when it is a ARM Binary

Answer (score 3):

Just use a **space** instead of a **`:`** between the ip-addr and the port

`telnet 10.0.2.15 2323`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the adb server is running

```
adb start-server
```

Telnet to the port on which the adb server is listening (typically 5554).

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Then on the telnet prompt, add a new redirection. The adb server will listens to an additional port 5000 and forward the traffic to the telnet service on port 2323 on the emulator.

```
redir add tcp:5000:2323
```

Now one can telnet to localhost with port 5000, adb server forwards this to the telnet server on the emulator

```
telnet localhost 5000
```